# React & Redux: Getting Undefined Error When Accessing Props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using Redux with React to manage my state; however, I get an `undefined` error whenever I try to access this particular state that looks good and accessible through Redux Chrome Extension **(Please See Image Below)**

[image]

Based on Redux Chrome Extension, memberDetails object should be available to all components through `this.props.memberDetails` but I get an `undefined` error.

The class I am accessing `memberDetails` from is as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Details extends Component {


    render = () => {
        const   memberDetails = this.props.memberDetails;
        console.log("memberDetails: ", memberDetails);
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Details;
```

Comment: If you can share some code around this would be helpful to add more context to see what you are doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use mapStateToProps function to get the memberDetails value from store.
Look at this. https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux' 
    class Details extends Component {


        render = () => {
            const   memberDetails = this.props.memberDetails;
            console.log("memberDetails: ", memberDetails);
            return (
                <div>

                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { memberDetails } = state
  return { memberDetails }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Details)
```

Comment: Yes I do have it passed in the reducer as   memberDetails: action.memberDetails

Comment: If redux chrome extensions shows it as such, then I believe the mapping should be correct otherwise it would not show...with the values and everything as expected...

Comment: have you used "connect" function from react-redux and mapStateToProps function ?

Comment: Yes, if you are aware of Redux Chrome Extension tools, you would see it is mapped correctly as in the attached image.

Comment: I have the same exact payload used in a different component and works fine, but this neighboring component, it does not...

Comment: post the component snippet where you are accessing memberDetails, please.

Comment: Please find the updated code in my comment, that is what i have been mentioning using mapStateToProps to get the store value and pass it to the component. Please read the react-redux link provided.

Comment: Yes but I already have that object mapped to state in a different file...Does it have to explicitly be mapped to that file as well. I mean the state of memberDetails is available globally already...

Comment: Yes, either you pass them from parent component or get it from the store using connect function. Please mark as solved if you found useful.

Comment: Yes when I do that it is still undefined.